# Why can't my test files be found when running mocha?

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I am following step 1 of this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ultravulturekangaroo/fullstack-tddd-mern-app-part-2-57844fca3bab)

I have the following folder structure:

```
├── lib
│ ├── json
│ │ ├── messages.json
│ │ └── testMessages.json
│ └── model.js
├── test
│ └── model.test.js
└── package.json
```

My `package.json` has the following to run the mocha tests

```
“test”: “mocha -r esm ./test/* —exit”,
```

But I get the following error

```
> backend@1.0.0 test /Users/lee33ya/Desktop/mern-app/backend
> mocha -r esm ./test/* --exit

Error: No test files found: "./test/*"
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to resolve my tests not running?

My [github](https://github.com/develijahlee/mern-app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found two issues

1. Your package.json file is misplaced. Place it with ".gitignore" file. And run "npm install"
2. "chai" is required. Do "npm install chai"

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

while doing a mocha test these things you should follow

1. first `npm init` this initializes the package.json file
2. Then add the following inside the package.json file
3. `"script": {"test" : "mocha"}` (this should be inside the main { })
4. then install mocha as a dependency by doing `npm install mocha -D`
5. then make a test folder in the main file and put the .js file you want to test
6. then run `npm test`

if i didn't explain correctly i am sorry and this is my first answer so :)

here is a very good article on mocha if you want to see

https://blog.logrocket.com/a-quick-and-complete-guide-to-mocha-testing-d0e0ea09f09d/